# n-gram model: why conditioning on the start symbol <s>?

Tags: natural-language-processing

[image]

from the [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/3.pdf), Speech and Language Processing (3rd ed. draft)

I understand conditioning on `<s>` will give context about the **first** word.

From the formula above, aren't we computing
`P(i want english food </s> | <s>)`, instead of `P(<s> i want english food </s>)`? Do we imply `p(<s>) = 1`?

The [n-gram wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_n-gram_language_model) implies same thing too:
[image]

---

edited on: 08/21/2023

I found a different definition for sentence probability from [this paper](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/25104739/tr-10-98.pdf), which is referenced by the above textbook.

[image]
[image]

I think the probability of a **sentence** in an n-gram language model is conditioned on `<s>`. The conditional probability forms a valid probability distribution.

This paper discards `<s>` and `</s>` in its notaion:

`P(I want food)`, instead of `P(<s> I want food </s>)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that exact textbook, but I assume you take `P(<s> | ε) = 1`, i.e., the first token is always `<s>`.

Comment: what's `ε`? you are conditioning on ε then.

Comment: Just the [empty string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string).  So, yes, you start with the empty string and continue from there, in which case `P(<s> | ε) = 1`.

Comment: Ps, `<BOS>` is the same as `<s>` and `<EOS>` the same as `</s>`

Comment: if all sentence is conditioned on `<s>`, the conditional distribution is still a valid probability distribution. I guess it's just a notation issue that people often omit the condition `| <s>` part. The paper I just added didn't use <s> at all.

Comment: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/47355/42373 I also found that given `<s>` will make n-gram a valid distribution over strings of any length.

Comment: `Think of a language model as a stochastic process` maybe helpful. Given `<s>`, generate a sentence using this model.